# GitLab CI - как установить эмулятор и запустить ui тесты

Tags: android, gitlab-ci, dockerfile, gitlab-runner, android-testing

Сколько вариантов перепробовал - ни один не работает.
Перебрал различные образы докеров - но в итоге тоже не смог добиться успеха.
На данный момент пытаюсь запустить эмулятор с помощью данного образа и конфига yml
https://github.com/jerbob92/gitlab-ci-android

и тут получаю такую проблему с аппаратным ускорением

> emulator: CPU Acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
> Please ensure KVM is properly installed and usable.
> CPU acceleration status: /dev/kvm is not found: VT disabled in BIOS or KVM kernel module not loaded
> error: no devices/emulators found
> error: no devices/emulators found
> Waiting for emulator to fully boot...
> error: no devices/emulators found
> Waiting for emulator to fully boot... и так бесконечно

Пробовал другие варианты, но там свои проблемы, и в целом примеры очень старые и не рабочие.
Буду рад любой подсказке.

Comment: или хотя бы возможно ли как-то прогнать тесты на эмуляторе без аппаратного ускорения путем отключения каких-либо функций?

Comment: слышал, что на KVM запускали

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov да, до этого я пытался ставить kvm внутри докера, это никак не помогало.
Все решилось когда kvm поставил на хост. 
Я бы с радостью твой комментарий выбрал бы лучшим ответом, будь он ответом, поскольку это единственное что мне помогло. 
Жду ответ от тебя ;)